# How to escape slashes in bash alias name?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, bash-alias

I want to make an alias like this:

```
alias /sbin/init="/path/to/my/script/sh"
```

However, when I try to source my .bashrc, it throws an error:

```
-bash: alias: `/sbin/init': invalid alias name
```

How do I properly escape those slashes and make Bash run my script rather than `/sbin/init` every time I type in `/sbin/init`?

Why do I need this? We have network mounted `$HOME`, so I got the same `.bashrc` on every machine. I'm tired of accidentally rebooting the wrong machine with `/sbin/init 6` and I want to prevent this from ever happening again. So I wrote a script that throws an error on machines that shouldn't be rebooted and does `/sbin/init $@` on the ones that should be. The only thing that's left is creating an alias that would intercept `/sbin/init` and stop these unintended reboots from happening anymore.

I tried to Google for this and in every single thread escaping special characters in alias **value** was discussed, rather than escaping them in its **name**.

Comment: Can't be done. This is not what aliases are for. I would instead suggest asking for a solution to avoid rebooting the wrong machine. Some simple workarounds would be using a `$PS1` which includes the hostname (possibly in colour in case it's a critical machine or you're SSHed into the current machine), not allowing rebooting as a regular user, or using `shutdown --reboot N` to reboot in N seconds rather than immediately.

Comment: @l0b0 I already color code the machine name in prompt, and reboots as regular user are forbidden. It just always happens in a hurry. Oh and I actually use `sudo /sbin/init 6` to reboot. I guess I could change my script a bit and do `alias sudo=/path/to/my/script`. All I'll have to do then is check if arguments contain literally `/sbin/init` and just do `sudo $@` if they don't. Thank you for the idea.